# DKIM failure when using Exim4 as an "edge transport" for Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exim, dkim

I have a server running Exim 4.72 that is set up similar to the Exchange "Edge Transport" role: it forwards mail from the internet to Exchange and forwards mail from exchange to the internet.

I configured DKIM in Exim for outgoing mail. It works properly when mail is sent directly to Exim; Gmail reports the body hash is correct. When sending to Exchange, which then forwards to Exim, the DKIM body hash check fails.

I tried with both simple and relaxed cannon. Anyone experience anything similar or have any insights?

Comment: When is Exim doing the DKIM signing?  If Exim is acting as a relay, remember that, typically, it will add a header stating that it picked up the message from another server.  If the header (or the message at all) is being altered after it's being signed, then the DKIM signature will be off.

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I suspect something is being changed in transit by exim.  Does your exim system by chance add a stock boilerplate to every outgoing message?  The DKIM signing must occur after that addition and include those changes so that it can include it in the body hash.

Generic Testing Procedure:

1. Capture one of the raw messages.  Change the recipient to your private mailbox so you can get a copy of the email that gets sent.  We'll assume the file with the message is named test.eml.  Save it somewhere on the exim server.
2. Temporarily configure exim to DKIM sign messages from localhost.  Don't restart exim, we're just testing this from the commandline.
3. On the server, pass the message to exim using a command like this:

   exim -d -t < test.eml > test.out 2>&1
4. When it finishes, there will be a resulting file named "test.out".  Edit that file and look for "PDKIM".  The first instance of that will be the canonicalized body.  The fourth instance or so will be the canonicalized headers.  Look at those sections and see if anything is changed, both compared to the original message you sent, and the message as it was received.
5. In general, look for anything regarding DKIM signing.  There will be copious amounts of data, so it may take quite a bit of digging to find it.
6. Make sure that there is nothing being added by any transports AFTER the DKIM signature has been generated.
7. Remove the temporary config setting allowing exim to sign emails from localhost.

Typical changes I've seen usually have to do with the mime version, mime type, content transfer encoding, content type, or charset being changed in transit.  However, you said that your header checks pass and your body check doesn't.  So that makes it more complicated.